# Unable to access id tag in fragment_main

Tags: java, android, setcontentview

So I have the following code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

     savedSearches = getSharedPreferences(SEARCHES, MODE_PRIVATE); 

      // store the saved tags in an ArrayList then sort them
      tags = new ArrayList<String>(savedSearches.getAll().keySet());
      Collections.sort(tags, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER); 

      // create ArrayAdapter and use it to bind tags to the ListView
      adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, tags);

      System.out.println(R.id.list);
      ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
      lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}
```

The problem is that lv is null after I instantiate it. I know that R.id.list exists, since it returns an int as expected. I believe the problem is that R.id.list is in R.layout.fragment_main instead of R.layout.activity_main(since setContentView sets it to R.layout.activity_main). However, I need to use activity_main for the setContentView. Any ideas on how to fix this? Most places online just said this was the problem, but didn't give an answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is null because you are accessing a view from a different layout which your activity did not use.

**solution:**

1: You can transfer your ListView from `fragment_main` into your `activity_main`

**or**

2: You can start a fragment and set your `fragment_main` as a layout to of the fragment and from there you can then instantiate your ListView.